# Why won't Launchpad create a .db file? Restarts reset Launchpad

Tags: macos, terminal, launchpad

Launchpad will not create a .db file in ~/Library/Application Support/Dock to save the state of Launchpad.

It always resets to default upon restart. I have tried many terminal commands, the most recent being:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ; killall Dock

defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

How can I force Launchpad to create this file?

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of the `/Dock` folder. If that's all good, try this issue out in a new administrator user over in System Preferences > Users & Groups.

Comment: Permissions are I (admin) have Read and Write.

I created a new admin, and tested this out. I rearranged Launchpad layout and restart. The new layout saves, but ironically no .db file is created in the /Dock folder. It must be saving the file elsewhere.